# Can ffmpeg copy codec settings from an "etalon" ("perfect example") file?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to re-encode a video "exactly like this one". Can I somehow export codecs and container settings from the example file and import them during the encoding process (except the obvious manual solution)?

I'm not copying the compression settings from the *input* file. There is LosslessCut for this (it also prevents the re-encoding at all). I want to take those settings them from an *example* file and apply them for re-encoding *other* files.

I want to achieve a full compatibility with videos taken by a particular camera. Including the ability to play them by that camera (of course, it's decoder is hard-coded and lacks compatibility), and merging the videos from that camera with re-encoded ones losslessly (so LosslessCut must take both camera videos and re-encoded ones as exactly the same format).

Comment: My Google powers are a little weak: what is an 'etalon' file?

Comment: Probably my English driven me into a "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend" problem again. I mean this etalon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_(metrology) I've fixed the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

## No such feature

When encoding `ffmpeg` will automatically attempt to copy some settings (width, height, frame rate, sample rate, channel layout, pixel format, etc). But it has no such feature to automatically copy **all** of the encoding settings from the input to the output. It's not really possible.

## Stream copy

But you can stream copy (re-mux) instead of encode which is like a copy and paste:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy output.mkv
```

Perhaps that will achieve what you are trying to do.

## Manual method

See example at [ffmpeg: transcode using same codec and params as input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34457444).

I am the author but I don't recommend doing this.

## It's usually not a good idea

Trying to copy settings is almost always an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

For example, a user may want to copy settings to get a video to play on a particular device. The result is often overly complicated with a suboptimal output when the actual solution is usually much simpler.

If you explain what you are actually trying to achieve we can give a more accurate answer.

Comment: I've tried to explain. Thanks for the example, it can be changed a bit to work with two different videos but I afraid the Size/Duration ratio is not enough to guess the exact quantization coefficient table :( so videos will not allow to merge streams losslessly (I understand it's not the "completely lossless" operation because the re-encoding I'm asking for can't be lossless, but I'm trying to keep the "etalon"/example intact and re-encode only one of two videos I'm trying to merge).

Comment: @NickDoom So the real question seems to be, "How to make video that plays in a particular camera?". Best way to do that is to provide a sample file from the camera. I can then give you a ffmpeg command that attempts to provide a compatible output. This isn't always easy though due to pickiness of cameras.